Movie with a lab full of monster
In 2011, I saw an English-language TV movie. I only saw a few fragments of the movie. This is the plot, from what I've seen.  
A lab is constructed in the desert. Many soldiers guard the lab. Inside the lab various creatures roam about freely. Many of the creatures are insect-like. Scientists are collecting specimens. I don't know whether the creatures have been bred or not. The scientists are wearing some kind of HAZMAT suit. I think the air is poisonous inside the lab. The scene I saw is mainly at night. I think it's a family movie. Not much blood is shown.
Update:
I believe it's an action movie, with no cartoon characters. There are also flesh eating plants.

Im tempted to say https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAzVXyT2dTM

no it's not mixed with cartoon characters

By "not much blood is shown" do you mean there is some blood or no blood at all? Thanks!

I thought of this straight away, after reading the title

Possible duplicate of Movie with lots of different monsters with orange goop

How about Evolution (2001)? An asteroid crashes on earth and develops alien life. Scientists build a dome around it and the protagonists enter it with hazmat suits to explore it. Some bugs are around, one of them even enters the hazmat suit and this happens in the middle of the desert.



